# Stateful quartz job starts running on node 2 before it finishes execution on node 1

Tags: quartz-scheduler

We have a stateful quartz job which is responsible for sending an update to an external system using webservice for each record in a database table (only one message has to be sent to the external system per record). If the update to external system is successful, then the record is deleted from the database.

The trigger is configured to fire every 6 seconds. And the job normally finishes execution in 1 second. Our application runs in a clustered environment. And we have the following in our quartz.properties file

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
```

Since this is a stateful job we expected it not to execute concurrently. It was working as expected almost all the time. But once in a while, we see the job running concurrently which causes some issues for us.

The timing of the executions is as below:

Node 1:

```
Trigger 1 start time - 14:54:12 (picks record with id 10)
Trigger 1 end time   - 14:54:33 (finishes after trigger 2 and tries to delete the record which is already deleted by trigger 2)
```

Node 2:

```
Trigger 2 start time - 14:54:22 (this also picks the record with id 10)
Trigger 2 end time   - 14:54:23 (finishes before trigger 1 and deletes the record in the database)
```

We haven't set the org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval property, so it has to be 15000 ms as per quartz 1.x documentation (we use quartz 1.6.0).

We checked the system time on the nodes and they are in sync.

Could someone please help me in understanding the reason for this issue?

And how is the job trigger frequency related to org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using @DisallowConcurrentExecution?

http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example4